# NullPointerException when object is instantiated

Tags: nullpointerexception

This is a homework, I would appreciate any kind of answer.

Im trying to figure out why i keep getting a NullPointerException when i call the equals method. I have instantiated the object if im not mistaken, but it still doesn't work.

```
Exception in thread "main" 8
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at labbfyra.TextBuilder.equals(TextBuilder.java:69)
    at labbfyra.SkapaOrd.main(SkapaOrd.java:17)
```

Is this the stacktrace?

```
public class TextBuilder {

    private static class Node{
        public char   inChar;
        public Node   next;

        public Node(char c, Node nästa){
            inChar = c;
            next = nästa;

        }
    }

    private  Node   first = null;
    private Node   last = null;

    public TextBuilder(){
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    public void append(String s){
        int x = s.length();
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){


            Node   n  = new Node(s.charAt(i),null);


            if(first ==null){
                first = n;
                last = n;

            }else{
                last.next = n;
                last = n;

            }
        }
    }

    public int ShowSize(){
        int counter = 0;

        Node   n = first;
        while(n!=null){
            counter++;
            n=n.next;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public boolean equals(String s){

        boolean   eq = false;
        int   counter = 0;
        char[]   cArray = s.toCharArray();
        char[]   cArrayComp = new char[10];


        Node   n = first;
        cArrayComp[counter] = n.inChar;

        while(n!=null){
            counter++;
            n=n.next;
            cArrayComp[counter] = n.inChar; //THIS IS LINE 69
        }
        if(cArrayComp==cArray){
                eq = true;
        }   
        else{
            eq=false;
        }
        return eq;
    }
}
```

Comment: post your stacktrace so we know where exactly you are getting the nullpointer.

Comment: I have edited the post, plz tell me if thats the correct information.

Comment: Issue is at line 69 as told in the exception. i cant see which is line 69 in your code

Comment: Sorry for that, I have marked line 69 in the code now. Scroll down to the equals method and you should be able to see it, Otherwise let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your while loop, you check that n is not null, but then you assign n.next to n just before accessing n. The problem is that you do not ensure that the assigned value (n.next) is not null.

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, looks like the counter variable in your while loop is going past the 10 you set your cArrayComp size to. Perhaps the string parameter being passed is longer than 10 chars?

Comment: Ive tried to change that value, and my string is 7 chars long. But should it give me a nullpointerexceptin? should'nt it give me an indexoutofbound exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(String s){

    boolean   eq = false;
    int   counter = 0;
    char[]   cArray = s.toCharArray();

    char[]   cArrayComp = new char[10];


    Node   n = first;

    while(n!=null){
        System.out.println(counter);


        cArrayComp[counter] = n.inChar;

        System.out.println(cArrayComp[counter]);
        System.out.println(n.inChar);

        n=n.next;
        counter++;

    }
    if(cArrayComp==cArray){
            eq = true;
    }   
    else{
        eq=false;
    }
    return eq;
}
```

This is the corrected version, i found a bug in your loop. Just check my version. Works at 100%

Comment: Explications: this is because you did a n.first before the loop. Thus when the loop start it will be shifted by 1.

Comment: worked perfectly, I see the problem now. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: don't forget the +1 :D ! Kidding